# How to add exception rule for unicorn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn

I'am use `unicorn` on server. I have a problem, when upload large csv file occurs timeout. Can add to `Unicorn` exception rule for url where the timeout will not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must make a upload in Background. Please see gem [sucker_punch](https://github.com/brandonhilkert/sucker_punch)